# onSaveInstanceState not saving images on rotation

Tags: android, screen-rotation, savestate

I want to save two images, so that they are still displaying in the imageviews after screen rotation. Somehow it does not work and I don't know why. onRestoreInstanceState dind't work either. Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
private byte[] mapImage;
private byte[] photo;
private Bitmap imageBitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_entry);
    if(savedInstanceState !=null) {
        photo = savedInstanceState.getByteArray(STATE_PHOTO);
        viewPhoto.setImageBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getImage(photo));

        mapImage = savedInstanceState.getByteArray(STATE_MAP);
        viewGPS.setImageBitmap(DbBitmapUtility.getImage(mapImage));

    }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(imageBitmap!=null) {
        photo = DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(imageBitmap);
        outState.putByteArray(STATE_PHOTO, photo);
    }
    if(mapImage !=null) {
        outState.putByteArray(STATE_MAP, mapImage);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void showMapView() {
    Bundle getImageOfMap = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (getImageOfMap != null) {
        mapImage = (byte[]) getImageOfMap.get("map_image");
        Bitmap showMapImage = DbBitmapUtility.getImage(mapImage);
        viewGPS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewGPS.setImageBitmap(showMapImage);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I put super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); on top of the onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method and now mapImage is being shown after rotation but imageBitmap still isn't. I found out that the imageBitmap is saved but in onCreate it is null.
Does someone know a solution for this?

2. EDIT: mapImage is now somehow saved without savedInstanceState, because when I delete the mapImage part it is still there after rotation. It didn't use to be like this when I posted this question first. I give up...
   I think I'll just use the not so pretty solution of the configChanges in the manifest. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Thanks!

Comment: where photo and mapImage objects are being initialized?

Comment: I added the code to my question

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. I think you should be checking for `imageBitmap != null`  instead of `photo != null`:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(imageBitmap!=null) {
        photo = DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(imageBitmap);
        outState.putByteArray(STATE_PHOTO, photo);
    }
    if(mapImage !=null) {
        outState.putByteArray(STATE_MAP, mapImage);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

EDIT:

Also, make sure that `onCreate()`, you initialize your `viewPhoto` (and other variables)

`viewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewPhoto);`

before access it inside the `if` block.

Comment: what does the log say when it crashed? maybe the `viewPhoto` in `onCreate()` is null. remember that your activity was destroyed upon rotation so you have to reinitialize your variables.

Comment: so in onCreate, make sure that your viewPhoto (and other variables) is not null. see my edit.

Comment: I reinitialized the variables and now it's not crashing but still the images are not saved

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is a threarding issue. Maybe your image size is more. Try saving the bytearray in some other thread. Better use an AsyncTask to save the byre array.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app is running on API21+ version of Android, your

public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState);

will NOT be called as it simply does not exist on earlier versions of the platform than 21. To support pre API21 devices you must, instead of the above, override the following method:

public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState);

This will work on API21+ as well, so you do not need to override both methods, of course (unless you know you need to deal with PersistableBundle the new one offers).

Can you once confirm about onSaveInstanceState calling means it's called or not?

Comment: I am overriding `public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState);`